# Not able to see Response Body Preview in the web Browser

Tags: html, python-2.7, web-services, python-requests, python-server-pages

```
 import codecs
 def do_GET_Index(self):

    self.set_HTTP_headers(200)

    HtmlFile3 = codecs.open('server/entry_template.html', 'r','utf-8')
    html_response = HtmlFile3.read()

    self.wfile.write(html_reponse)
```

Iam running these in a python server ip: 10.1.0.1

In my firefox I entered **http://10.1.0.1** But i couldn't see anything in the browser.??

My entry_template.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in Advance!!!